# cucumber hooks in example tags

Tags: cucumber, hook

How to read the tag name of the example in cucumber before hook.

@feature_tag
Feature: Feature description

@outline_tag
  Scenario Outline: Outline description
    Given scenario details

```
@example_tag
Examples:
  |num_1  | num_2  | result |
  | 1        |   1       |   2     |
```

I want to print  "@example_tag" in output.

used java code as

```
@Before
public void beforeScenario (ScenarioOutline ScenarioOutline) {
     examples = (Examples) ScenarioOutline.getExamples(); 
     for(Tag tag : examples.getTags()){
       System.out.println("Example Tags: " + tag.getName());
    }
}
```

But getting error as

"Failure in before hook:StepDefinitions.beforeScenario(ScenarioOutline)
Message: cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: When a hook declares an argument it must be of type cucumber.api.Scenario. public void stepDefinitions.beforeScenario(gherkin.ast.ScenarioOutline)"

---

Thank you for the response but this code is printing "@outline_tag" and not the "@example_tag". That was my question. I want "@example_tag" to be printed.

```
@feature_tag 
Feature: Feature description

@outline_tag 
Scenario Outline: Outline description Given scenario details

@example_tag
Examples:
  |num_1  | num_2  | result |
  | 1     |   1    |   2    |
```

Answer (score 1):

The "Before" block does not run before a scenario outline. It runs before a scenario. The scenario outline is broken up into multiple scenarios, meaning you just want to just grab the scenario that is generated:

```
@Before
public void beforeScenario(Scenario scenario) {
    for(String tag : scenario.getSourceTagNames()){
        System.out.println("Example Tags: " + tag);
    }
}
```

Each scenario from the scenario outline will hit that before it runs.

```
@stuff @stuff1
Feature: Stuff

Scenario Outline: More stuff
  When some step

  @somegabage
  Examples:
    | provider |
    | 123      |
    | 123567   |
```

outputs:

```
Example Tags: @stuff
Example Tags: @stuff1
Example Tags: @stuff2
Example Tags: @somegabageExample Tags: @stuff
Example Tags: @stuff1
Example Tags: @stuff2
Example Tags: @somegabage
```

Comment: Thank you for the response but this code is printing "@outline_tag" and not the "@example_tag". That was my question. I want "@example_tag" to be printed.

Comment: I provided some examples for you. It prints all the tags. If you don't ever want to see the @outline tag, then you'll need to do some other work (like ignoring specific tags in the for loop). Out of the box, I don't believe there is any way to differentiate between a scenario and a scenario outline at this point.